# How to force the order of the joins to improve query performance in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a sql statement

```
SELECT count(*)
From table1 
inner join table2 on condition1
..
inner join tableN on conditionN-1
inner join problematic_table on tableN.FKColumn= problematic_table.FKColumn
```

This yields result in 20-25 seconds.

If I run the query like this, it runs faster. In 100ms

```
select count(*)
from problematic_table where problematic_table.FKColumn in (
select distinct tableN.FKColumn
    From table1 
    inner join table2 on condition1
    ..
    inner join tableN on conditionN-1
)
```

I want to point out that the joins of tables from table1 to tableN have no result (are empty).

So why is the performance in the first case that bad?

**EDIT:**
When running EXPLAIN the tables are sorted on a different order from the order that I have written in JOIN

**EDIT2**
So for the first query, the problemati_table join is not run last, but the queries who actually reduce the number of rows to 0 are run last.
For the second query is the same order except the problematic_table is at the top 
with id=1 and select_type=Primary, the others are id=2 and select_type=MATERIALIZED.

So I guess the question becomes how to make the engine run the query in the order I wrote it to?

**EDIT3**

what might be the case is that the joins conditions that are run last by the engine are TABLE1 and TABLE2 which are of form:

```
SELECT
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 on TABLE1.COLUMN1='constant_string' and TABLE2.COLUMN2='constant_string2'
INNER JOIN ... other tables have proper join conditions between colums of the tables.
```

**EDIT4**
Changed the title of the questions to attract others that may face the same issue.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#:~:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20statements.&text=That%20is%2C%20MySQL%20explains%20how,joined%20and%20in%20which%20order.) to find out.

Comment: show  valid sample  ..  your inner join table2 on condition1  is too vague  and for performance you should avoid IN clause

Comment: Do the conditions matter? The joins from table1 to tableN yield 0 results and its fast.
Why does 0 results inner join table takes 20 seconds?

Comment: Your question is too generic. It lacks enough details for us to help you. What indexes does the table `problematic_table` have?

Comment: The joining columns are foreign keys in both tables "problematic_table" and "tableN".

Comment: You have to compare the EXPLAINs from each query and see how they differ.

Comment: "When running EXPLAIN the tables are sorted on a different order from the order that I have written in JOIN" -- Of course. SQL is a **declarative** language, not an **imperative** one. The engine will rewrite, rephrase, optimize, clean the query as much as it can, in order to make it cheap. It won't run the exact code you wrote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited

Comment: @TheImpaler made 3 edits total

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972444/performance-of-multiple-joins

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I fixed the issue. (See my answer)

Comment: Btw, `TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 on TABLE2.COLUMN1='constant_string' and TABLE2.COLUMN2='constant_string2'` is not a proper equi-join, it's a CROSS join with some conditons

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAINs`.  It is very rare for `IN ( SELECT ...)` to run faster than some other formulation; are you sure you got the correct results?  What version of MySQL; there have been optimization changes in this area.

Comment: Does table1 have a composite index on `(col1, col2)` (in either order)?

Comment: Hey, sorry I had a typo on my EDIT3. No theres no index, but the constant comparision on the join, are almost on Unique (logical unique, no index) column, so there should be almost always 1 row out of 130k from each table, so basically the table1 join table2 would return 0-1 rows like 99.9999999% of the time. Since the table1 and table 2 are applied last by the engine, we have some million rows records before joining with table 1 and table 2. However when I force the order (see my answer) there is never an "intermediary step" when there are that many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the engine was running the joins in an order that was performing badly.
I fixed the issue by using the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` optimizer hint instead of simple `INNER JOIN`

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces the order; it does not "fix the _underlying_ problem" of an Optimizer problem.  And, any hints like that may "help today, but hurt tomorrow" (when the dataset changes).

Comment: @Rick This case fits the "I know that it will not be the case scenario". See my last comment on the question.